# Is fasting on Hanukkah prohibited

Tags: halacha, chanuka, fast-days, simchah-joy-happiness, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, is it prohibited to fast on Hanukkah like it is on Yom Tov, Shabbat, Rosh Chodesh, and Chol Hamoed?

Or, unlike those times, is it permissible to voluntarily fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rambam writes in MT [Hilchot Megillah v'Chanukah (3:3)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952008/jewish/Megillah-vChanukah-Chapter-Three.htm) that **it is prohibited to fast on Hanukah**

> **Accordingly, the Sages of that generation ordained that these eight
> days, which begin from the twenty-fifth of Kislev, should be
> commemorated to be days of happiness and praise [of God].** Candles
> should be lit in the evening at the entrance to the houses on each and
> every one of these eight nights to publicize and reveal the miracle.
>
> These days are called Chanukah. It is forbidden to eulogize and fast
> on them, as on the days of Purim.

The Shulchan Aruch ([OC 670:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.670.1?lang=bi)) writes the same

> On the 25th of Kislev (start) the eight days of Hanukkah, and **they are
> prohibited for eulogizing and fasting**, but are permitted for doing
> work.

The fast for the amelioration of a dream is a common exception (see [568:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.568.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: Another important exception (relevant this past year) is a series of fasts that began before Chanukah started and continues into Chanukah